# Multi Dimensional Byte Array In Kotlin

Tags: multidimensional-array, kotlin

I have the following function in c#

```
public static byte[][] TagSplits(byte[][] splitArray, byte[] original, byte[] guid)
{
   byte[] temp;

   for (var a = 0; a < splitArray.Length; a++)
   {

   }
}
```

I am trying to convert the following code to Kotlin code, I have ended up with the following code:

```
companion object
{
    fun TagSplits(splitArray:  ByteArray, original: ByteArray, guid: ByteArray): ByteArray
    {

        var temp: ByteArray

        for(a in 0..splitArray.size)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

How would I be able to declare a multidimensional byte array in Kotlin as in the c# code base? For the input parameters for the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays do not have special syntax in Kotlin. There are two ways how to work with arrays:

- Using the specialized types `ByteArray`, `IntArray` etc. These correspond to Java `byte[]`, `int[]` arrays.
- Using the generic type `Array<T>`. This corresponds to a Java array of references `T[]`.

You can achieve the nesting using `Array<ByteArray>`, but probably there is a better way of achieving what exactly you need. Alternatives are `List<ByteArray>` or a more high-level OOP representation of the byte patterns.

Answer (score 2):

`ByteArray` is an object (reference type), so you can create an array of it: `Array<ByteArray>`.